# How to update value for all rows in table A should update all corresponding column values in table b and c

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column x with different value for each record in a table of 60 records, and when I update this column in table A ,the column value for this particular column x must also be updated in table b and table c with column x value. Here column x is primary key in table b and c but not in table a.

Comment: You can update all 3 tables at the same time. UPDATE queries can specify multiple tables. Read the manual.

Comment: @Dan: Why don't you write your comment as an answer? Obviously OP did not know that one could do that and it's a valid answer (and probably the best, far better than triggers anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This is what [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) are for.

An example taken from the documentation:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

This example does not modify a second table, but that can be done with triggers as well--possibly using a stored procedure.

Comment: There are examples included in the documentation I linked you to.